# Unexplained files found in home folder

Tags: linux, files, security

For background information, I'm running openSUSE 13.2 and KDE 5.

Today I found a number of unexplained files and folders in my home folder which state they've been edited 3 days ago. I do not remember doing anything that day that may have generated these files, nor did I download them as I don't even know what these files are or why they're there.

The names of the unexplained files can be seen below:

```
apr_crypto_openssl.so
apr_dbm_db.so
apr_dbm_gdbm.so
berkeley_db_svc-4.2
cpio
db_archive-4.2
db_archive-4.8
db_checkpoint-4.2
db_checkpoint-4.8
db_deadlock-4.2
db_deadlock-4.8
db_dump185-4.2
db_dump185-4.8
db_dump-4.2
db_dump-4.8
db_hotbackup-4.8
db_load-4.2
db_load-4.8
db_printlog-4.2
db_printlog-4.8
db_recover-4.2
db_recover-4.8
db_sql-4.8
db_stat-4.2
db_stat-4.8
db_upgrade-4.2
db_upgrade-4.8
db_verify-4.2
db_verify-4.8
errno.h
fcntl.h
float.h
floatingpoint.h
hoststat
ld-elf.so.1
libalias.so
libapr-1.so
libarchive.so
libaria2.so
libasn1.so
libauditd.so
libavl.so
libbegemot.so
libbiconv.so
libBlocksRuntime.so
libbluetooth.so
libbsdxml.so
libbsm.so
libbsnmp.so
libbsnmptools.so
libbz2.so
libcalendar.so
libcam.so
libcom_err.so
libcrypto.so
libcrypt.so
libc.so
libctf.so
libcurses.a
libcurses_p.a
libcurses.so
libcursesw.a
libcursesw_p.a
libcursesw.so
libdb-4.2.so
libdb-4.2.so.2
libdb-4.8.so
libdb-4.8.so.0
libdb-4.so
libdb_cxx-4.2.so
libdb_cxx-4.2.so.2
libdb_cxx-4.8.so
libdb_cxx-4.8.so.0
libdb_cxx-4.so
libdb_cxx.so
libdb.so
libdevinfo.so
libdevstat.so
libdialog.so
libdtrace.so
libdwarf.so
libedit.so
libelf.so
libexpat.so
libfetch.so
libform.so
libformw.so
libftpio.so
libgcc.a
libgcc_p.a
libgcc_s.so
libgcj.so
libgdbm.so
libgeom.so
libgettextlib.so
libgettextpo.so
libgmp.so.10
libgmpxx.so
libgmpxx.so.4
libgnuregex.so
libgomp.so
libgpib.so
libgssapi_krb5.so
libgssapi_ntlm.so
libgssapi.so
libgssapi_spnego.so
libhdb.so
libheimntlm.so
libhistory.so
libhx509.so
libiconv.so
libintl.so
libipsec.so
libitm.so
libjail.so
libkadm5clnt.so
libkadm5srv.so
libkafs5.so
libkiconv.so
libkrb5.so
libkvm.so
liblwres.so
liblzma.so
liblzo2.so.2
libmagic.so
libmd.so
libmemstat.so
libmenu.so
libmenuw.so
libmilter.so
libmpc.so
libmpfr.so
libmpfr.so.4
libmp.so
libm.so
libmudflapth.so
libncp.so
libncurses.so
libncursesw.so
libneon.so
libneon.so.27
libnetgraph.so
libngatm.so
libnvpair.so
libodialog.so
libopie.so
libpam.so
libpanel.so
libpanelw.so
libpcap.so
libpcre16.so
libpcre32.so
libpcreposix.so
libpcre.so
libpkg.so
libpmc.so
libproc.so
libprocstat.so
libpthread.a
libpthread_p.a
libpthread.so
libpython2.7.so
libradius.so
libreadline.so
libroken.so
librpcsec_gss.so
librpcsvc.so
librtld_db.so
librt.so
libsbuf.so
libsdp.so
libserf-1.so
libserf-1.so.1
libsmb.so
libssh.so
libssl.so
libssp.so
libstdbuf.so
libstdc++.so
libsupc++.so
libsvn_client-1.so
libsvn_client-1.so.0
libsvn_delta-1.so
libsvn_delta-1.so.0
libsvn_diff-1.so
libsvn_diff-1.so.0
libsvn_fs-1.so
libsvn_fs-1.so.0
libsvn_fs_fs-1.so
libsvn_fs_util-1.so
libsvn_ra-1.so
libsvn_ra_local-1.so
libsvn_ra_local-1.so.0
libsvn_ra_serf-1.so
libsvn_repos-1.so
libsvn_subr-1.so
libsvn_wc-1.so
libsvn_wc-1.so.0
libtacplus.so
libtermcap.a
libtermcap_p.a
libtermcap.so
libtermcapw.a
libtermcapw_p.a
libtermcapw.so
libtermlib.a
libtermlib_p.a
libtermlib.so
libtermlibw.a
libtermlibw_p.a
libtermlibw.so
libthread_db.so
libthr.so
libtinfo.a
libtinfo_p.a
libtinfo.so
libtinfow.a
libtinfow_p.a
libtinfow.so
libufs.so
libugidfw.so
libulog.so
libumem.so
libusbhid.so
libusb.so
libutempter.a
libutempter_p.a
libutempter.so
libutil.so
libuutil.so
libvgl.so
libwrap.so
libxml2.so.2
libypclnt.so
libzfs_core.so
libzfs.so
libzpool.so
libz.so
linker_set.h
log.0000000001
mailq
ncurses.h
newaliases
nologin
pam_chroot.so
pam_deny.so
pam_echo.so
pam_exec.so
pam_ftpusers.so
pam_group.so
pam_guest.so
pam_krb5.so
pam_ksu.so
pam_lastlog.so
pam_login_access.so
pam_nologin.so
pam_opieaccess.so
pam_opie.so
pam_passwdqc.so
pam_permit.so
pam_radius.so
pam_rhosts.so
pam_rootok.so
pam_securetty.so
pam_self.so
pam_ssh.so
pam_tacplus.so
pam_unix.so
perl
perl5
pgrep
pkg-config
pkill
poll.h
purgestat
sched.h
_semaphore.h
sendmail
snmp_atm.so
snmp_bridge.so
snmp_hast.so
snmp_hostres.so
snmp_mibII.so
snmp_netgraph.so
snmp_pf.so
snmp_target.so
snmp_usm.so
snmp_vacm.so
snmp_wlan.so
stdarg.h
stdint.h
strange_files.7z
svnpubsub
svnwcsub
Sync
syslog.h
tar
ucontext.h
```

The file log.0000000001 was generated when I ran the executable db_printlog however I tried opening the log file in kwrite and was met with the error:

`The file /home/(redacted)/log.0000000001 was opened with UTF-8 encoding but contained invalid characters.
It is set to read-only mode, as saving might destroy its content.
Either reopen the file with the correct encoding chosen or enable the read-write mode again in the menu to be able to edit it.`

The files svnwcsub and svnpubsub are shell scripts and their contents are as follows:

svnwcsub:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# PROVIDE: svnwcsub
# REQUIRE: DAEMON
# KEYWORD: shutdown

. /etc/rc.subr

name="svnwcsub"
rcvar=`set_rcvar`

load_rc_config $name

#
# DO NOT CHANGE THESE DEFAULT VALUES HERE
# SET THEM IN THE /etc/rc.conf FILE
#
svnwcsub_enable=${svnwcsub_enable-"NO"}
svnwcsub_user=${svnwcsub_user-"svnwc"}
svnwcsub_group=${svnwcsub_group-"svnwc"}
svnwcsub_pidfile=${svnwcsub_pidfile-"/var/run/svnwcsub/svnwcsub.pub"}
svnwcsub_env="PYTHON_EGG_CACHE"
svnwcsub_cmd_int=${svnwcsub_cmd_int-"python"}
svnwcsub_config=${svnwcsub_config-"/etc/svnwcsub.conf"}
svnwcsub_logfile=${svnwcsub_logfile-"/var/log/svnwcsub/svnwcsub.log"}
pidfile="${svnwcsub_pidfile}"

export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE="/var/run/svnwcsub"

command="/usr/local/svnpubsub/svnwcsub.py"
command_interpreter="/usr/local/bin/${svnwcsub_cmd_int}"
command_args="--daemon \
              --logfile=${svnwcsub_logfile} \
              --pidfile=${pidfile} \
              --uid=${svnwcsub_user} --gid=${svnwcsub_group} \
              --umask=002 \
          ${svnwcsub_config}"

run_rc_command "$1"
```

svnpubsub:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# PROVIDE: svnpubsub
# REQUIRE: DAEMON
# KEYWORD: shutdown

. /etc/rc.subr

name="svnpubsub"
rcvar=`set_rcvar`

load_rc_config $name

#
# DO NOT CHANGE THESE DEFAULT VALUES HERE
# SET THEM IN THE /etc/rc.conf FILE
#
svnpubsub_enable=${svnpubsub_enable-"NO"}
svnpubsub_user=${svnpubsub_user-"svn"}
svnpubsub_group=${svnpubsub_group-"svn"}
svnpubsub_reactor=${svnpubsub_reactor-"poll"}
svnpubsub_pidfile=${svnpubsub_pidfile-"/var/run/svnpubsub/svnpubsub.pid"}
svnpubsub_cmd_int=${svnpubsub_cmd_int-"python"}
pidfile="${svnpubsub_pidfile}"

export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE="/home/svn/.python-eggs"

command="/usr/local/bin/twistd"
command_interpreter="/usr/local/bin/${svnwcsub_cmd_int}"
command_args="-y /usr/local/svnpubsub/svnpubsub.tac \
            --logfile=/var/log/vc/svnpubsub.log \
            --pidfile=${pidfile} \
            --uid=${svnpubsub_user} --gid=${svnpubsub_user} \
            -r${svnpubsub_reactor}"


run_rc_command "$1"
```

If anybody can shed some light on what these files are, where they may have come from and what their purpose is, that'd be great. If you need any additional information just ask

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention - is it possible my system may be compromised and these files are a keylogger or something similar? I run no web facing services and keep my router firewall and opensuse firewall on at all times

Comment: This looks suspicious to me...

Comment: Is there anything I can do to try to trace where the files may have come from? Since posting I have put them all into an archive and deleted them so they can't do any more potential damage

Comment: You might want to audit your log files from the approximate time that these files appear to have been modified. This stuff looks like source files and some version control files. If you haven't installed any software recently then I would start looking for what all went on during that time period.

Comment: Which log files specifically should I check?

Comment: My first thought was that you may have accidentally copied files from a number of system directories to ~ by some kind of typo in a command. But it does seem odd that you have just a couple of .h files. Have you checked if you have identical files anywhere else on your system?

Comment: FWIW, _svnwcsub_ and _svnpubsub_ are server-side freebsd _rc.d_ scripts:  [`svnwcsub`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/server-side/svnpubsub/rc.d/svnwcsub.freebsd) & [`svnpubsub`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/server-side/svnpubsub/rc.d/svnpubsub.freebsd)...

Comment: @user3808334 i would start with the contents of '/var/log` and start with `boot.log`, `secure` and `message.log`. It it not totally clear if this is a server with a GUI or just a workstation, but if you are running any public facing services, start checking the relevant logs, Apache or any `.ssh` server logs for instance. These logs are regularly rotated so check the ones that correspond to the time period in question. You are looking for events that are near to the time that these files were modified... You may find that you did something to cause this, but the more info the better.

Comment: @don_crissti I tried looking for the above files on my FreeNAS server in case I downloaded them by mistake, however I could not find them in any of the directories which I have been working in

Comment: @datUser This is not a server with a GUI, just a workstation with no public facing services running. I will check those logs and report back

Comment: I'm going to conclude that these files were somehow copied over from my Freenas server during an FTP session. If anybody can suggest a way to check whether or not these exact same files exist on my FreeNAS server then let me know so I can confirm that this is the case

Comment: To compare the contents, I would just do an `ls -R > listing.txt` on the remote computer, fetch it, and diff the two listings. As a start you can sort both lists alphabetically and diff (the sorted lists won't show _where_ the files are, but once you have a match you can search in the original listing).

Comment: Try using `strings log.0000000001 | head -50` or `od -c log.0000000001 | head -50` to view that log file.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not remember doing anything that day that may have generated these files, nor did I download them as I don't even know what these files are or why they're there.

You can have a look at `history`, maybe there is a clue and you remember what could have caused this.

Since these files look a lot like they are part of your system, you can try to `locate` or `find` them. If they are part of your system, you can check with `diff -a -q file1 file2` if they are the same. If you copied them unintentionally, they should be the same. Also, are those really files or just symbolic links? Symbolic links have arrows in `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -l /opt/bin
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 May  5  2013 ao -> /opt/audio-overload/ao2.0
                                           ^-- arrow
```

*.so files usually are shared objects used for programme parts which are used by several different programmes (like DLLs under Windows), some other files like "cpio", "hoststat" or "tar" look like they are executables, the .h are C header files. All of these files are likely to be somewhere else on your system. So, my guess is that you unintentionally copied them to `.` or `~`.

If you suspect these files to be dangerous, you might upload them to sites like https://virusscan.jotti.org/ and see if they know something about them. Be aware that a negative result does not necessarily mean that they are harmless and a positive result does not necessarily mean that they are (part of) malware. But a positive result could at least give you hints in the right direction.